# Remove arrow in Emacs' ProofGeneral mode for Coq

Tags: emacs, coq, proof-general

I'm using ProofGeneral with Coq.  When I do C-c C-return, Emacs highlights the area Coq has processed.  This is nice. However, it inserts a '=>' on the next line, which overwrites the first two characters of your input.  For example, currently I'm looking at

```
Inductive Seq : Set :=
| MkSeq : Ants -> Form -> Seq.

=>ductive Prf : Set :=
| Init :
```

How can I get rid of that arrow?

**Update:**

I learned that if I turn fringe-mode on, the arrow is in the fringe and I can see all my typing.  I still want to kill it though.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have this problem when running Emacs in graphical mode? Which version of Emacs and PG are you using?

Comment: Yes, graphical mode.  Latest PG, Emacs 24.2.  Like I said, it's only when I have fringe-mode off.  But I couldn't find anything in the PG sources relating to fringe-mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha, just found it. This is an Emacs configuration, not a Proof General one, given in the `overlay-arrow-string` variable. To turn it off, just set the variable to `""` in your Emacs configuration puttng this in your `.emacs`:

```
(setq overlay-arrow-string "")
```

Comment: Thanks!! When I get home, I'll give you points when it works :)